# Which one is preferable? np.where or .loc?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I found two forms of replacing some values of a data frame based on a condition:

1. **.loc**

```
mask = df['param'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'param'] = 'new_value'
```

2. **np.where()**

```
mask = df['param'].isnull()
df['param'] = np.where(mask, 'new_value', df['param'])
```

Both forms work well, but which is the preferred one? And in relation to the question, when should I use **.loc** and when **np.where**?

Comment: It usually doesn't matter, but `np.where` is usually faster because working with NumPy directly avoids some pandas overheads. OTOH, using `loc` is considered the pandaic way of doing things. But that's just my opinion and this question is opinion based so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was an answer that was not based on tastes or opinions but on tangible reasons, but that's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, not a throughout test, but here's a sample. In each run (`loc`, `np.where`), the data is reset to the original random with seed.

## toy data 1

Here, there are more `np.nan` than valid values. Also, the column is of float type.

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'param': np.random.choice((1, np.nan), 1000000, p=(0.3,0.7))})

# loc
%%timeit
mask = df['param'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'param'] = 'new_value'
# 46.7 ms ± 177 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# np.where
%%timeit
mask = df['param'].isnull()
df['param'] = np.where(mask, 'new_value', df['param'])
# 86.8 ms ± 2.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

## toy data 2:

Here there are less `np.nan` than valid values, and the column is of object type:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'param': np.random.choice(("1", np.nan), 1000000, p=(0.7,0.3))})
```

same story:

```
df.loc[mask, 'param'] = 'new_value'
# 47.8 ms ± 350 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

df['param'] = np.where(mask, 'new_value', df['param'])
# 58.9 ms ± 1.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So contrary to @cs95's comment, `loc` seems to outperform `np.where`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, definitely these results seem to contradict what @cs95 pointed

Comment: This should be updated with a toy data where `param` is numerical, because `np.where` doesn't really excel on string data.

Answer (score 2):

for what it's worth, i'm working with a very large dataset (millions of rows, 100+ columns) and i was using df.loc for a simple substitution and it would often take literally hours. when i changed to np.where it worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs in jupyter notebook

```
np.random.seed(42)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(0, 10, 10000)})

%%timeit
df1["a"] = np.where(df1["a"] == 2, 8, df1["a"])
# 163 µs ± 3.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%%timeit
df1.loc[df1['a']==2,'a'] = 8
# 203 µs ± 2.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit
df1.loc[np.where(df1.a.values==2)]['a'] = 8
# 383 µs ± 9.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# I have a question about this, Why does df1.loc[np.where(df1.a.values==2), 'a']= 8 report an error

%%timeit
df1.iloc[np.where(df1.a.values==2),0] = 8
# 101 µs ± 870 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

I have a question about the third way of writing, Why does df1.loc[np.where(df1.a.values==2), 'a']= 8 report an error

Comment: IMO `df1` is too small to be representative of actual real-world dataframes. This could certainly skew the timings due to constant overheads.