# Setting the value to be negative

Tags: pandas

Following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"item":[1,2,3,4],"item1":['+ve','-ve','-ve','-ve']})
```

give

```
   item item1
0     1   +ve
1     2   -ve
2     3   -ve
3     4   -ve
```

I want to make `item` to be negative value if `item1` is -ve

I use the following code

```
df.loc[df["item1"]=="-ve","item"]=-df.loc[df["item1"]=="-ve","item"]
```

I get the right output:

```
   item item1
0     1   +ve
1    -2   -ve
2    -3   -ve
3    -4   -ve
```

But is that the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify solution with multiple by `-1`, it working same like your solution:

```
df.loc[df["item1"]=="-ve","item"] *= -1
```

Or multiple by `-1` or `1` by mask:

```
df["item"] *= np.where(df["item1"]=="-ve", -1, 1)
print (df)
   item item1
0     1   +ve
1     2   -ve
2     3   -ve
3     4   -ve
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `loc`, you can use `np.where`:

```
df['item']=np.where(df['item1']=='-ve',df['item'].mul(-1),df['item'])
df
 
   item item1
0     1   +ve
1    -2   -ve
2    -3   -ve
3    -4   -ve
```

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56328494/which-one-is-preferable-np-where-or-loc) answer helpful.